# Уникальная SQL-выборка по двум полям

Tags: sql

Есть ли какие-нибудь известные способы(или трюки) выборки уникальных комбинаций полей из таблицы?

Например, есть поля вида: Field1, Field2,...FieldN
Можно ли как-то выбрать только уникальные комбинации значений этих полей? 
Т.е если:

```
Field1 = A
Field2 = B
FieldN = C
```

то:

```
Field1 = B
Field2 = C
FieldN = A
```

считать идентичной предыдущей и отбрасывать.

Comment: Диалект SQL какой. придумать наверняка что то можно, но на разных СУБД запросы будут совершенно различны. Думаю надо разворачивать таблицу в вертикаль, и сравнивать наборы. Для этого может оказаться полезной функция ELT MySQL например

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такое в Postgresql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
  FROM tbl a
 WHERE ARRAY[a.fld1, a.fld2, ... a.fldn] = 
    (SELECT MIN(ARRAY[b.fld1, b.fld2, ... b.fldn])
       FROM tbl b
      WHERE ARRAY[a.fld1, a.fld2, ... a.fldn] <@ ARRAY[b.fld1, b.fld2, ... b.fldn] AND
            ARRAY[a.fld1, a.fld2, ... a.fldn] @> ARRAY[b.fld1, b.fld2, ... b.fldn]);
```

Сам не знаю сработает ли.